# Server written using asio (non boost) library gets the data only after a client disconnects

Tags: boost-asio, asio

This is my server session code that should read the incoming client data asynchronously. I am using a free standing read function. When I tested this using Google Test(using local host, and both client and server on same computer), it worked fine. I was able to connect to server using my test client and server used to establish connection and read the data coming from client.

But when I tested in client and server running on different computers, I observed that after connection is established, Server only receives first of the N data items sent by client. And that too when client disconnects after it has finished writing.

My head is spinning and I am not able to find out why. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

```
void ServerSession::doRead()
    {
        asio::async_read(socket_, asio::buffer(data_,maxLength),
        [this](std::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
            if(!ec || ec == asio::error::eof)
            {
                std::string msg{data_, length};
                
                addMessageToQueue(std::move(msg));
                
            }
            else
            {
                  socket_.close(); //force close the socket upon read error.
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`async_read` is documented](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read/overload1.html) as:

> This function is used to asynchronously read a certain number of bytes
> of data from a stream. It is an initiating function for an
> asynchronous operation, and always returns immediately. The
> asynchronous operation will continue until one of the following
> conditions is true:
>
> - The supplied buffers are full. That is, the bytes transferred is equal
>   to the sum of the buffer sizes.
> - An error occurred.

Apparently neither condition is satisfied until the client disconnects (which satisfies the criteria with the `asio::error::eof` error code).

Usually you need to

- use an application protocol with framing (such as `\r\n\r\n`, `Content-Length` or chunked encoding for HTTP) and an [CompletionCondition](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/CompletionCondition.html) that expresses that. You can also use one of the overloads of [`async_read_until`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read_until.html) which allows some common completion conditions.
- Alternatively you can reduce the `maxLength` to be practically much smaller than the expected payload so you will likely get an earlier completion
- Finally you can "de-optimize" by using the lowlevel [`AsyncReadStream`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AsyncReadStream.html) operation `async_read_some` directly. As e.g. the documentation for [`tcp::socket::async_read_some`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html) highlights, this is rarely what you want:

  > The read operation may not read all of the requested number of bytes. Consider using the async_read function if you need to ensure that the requested amount of data is read before the asynchronous operation completes)

Comment: Thanks ! I used async_read_until with delimiter \n and that floats my boat.  It has worked like a charm.... Thanks !!!